# how to use more that logical operator in c++?

Tags: c++

My code is trying to determine if a triangle with the following side lengths (`x`, `y`, `z`) is an isosceles triangle.
It doesn't work, my code is :

```
if(x == y && y != z || y == y && y != z || x == z && z != y){
    cout << "isosceles triangle" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but your code is wrong, and I think you should be able to figure this out. Take a look at y==y; why do you have that?

Comment: You need to show an MCVE.

Comment: *hint*: you almost certainly need some parentheses in there.

Comment: put extra parenthesis, you may have problem with priority between `&&` and `||`. (Note that currently, your code is equivalent to `if (y != z) {..}`)

Comment: English may not be your first language, but it is necessary to make your question clear for others. I hope my edit represents what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to separe each case with `(` `)`:

```
if((x == y && y != z) || (y == y && y != z) || (x == z && z != y) ){
```

so , you can have one case or another case or another case.

second:

```
y == y && y != z
```

is wrong (mathematically, not programmatically) this makes no sense for validating an isosceles triangle. the correct would be

```
y == z && x != z
```

the final result is

```
if((x == y && y != z) || (y == z && x != z) || (x == z && z != y) ){
```

Comment: && has a higher precedence than ||. If you want to think of it mathematically, the expression is like `x^y * y^z + y^y * y^z + x^z * z^y`, which is "fine" without parentheses, but could be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using parenthesis:

```
if ((x == y && y != z) || (y != z) || (x == z && z!= y))
{
 //...
}
```

I removed the expression `y == y` because it is always true.

Comment: So you can even simplify to `if (y != z)`... which is not the correct test neither.